# How to extract first 3 characters of jenkinsfile parameter

Tags: groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-pipeline-unit

I need to extract the first 3 characters of jenkinsfile parameter:

```
string(name: 'DB_Type', defaultValue: 'mysql'  )
```

I tried the following but this did not work:

```
prefix=${params.db_type}
prefix=prefix.substring(0,2)
```

Comment: You have a typo: `params.db_type` instead of `params.DB_Type`.

Comment: @Matt Schuchard Sorry for the typo, I tried with DB_Type, it does not work.

Comment: Describe "did not work"... Exception? Empty string?

Answer (score 2):

```
params.DB_Type?.substring(0,3)
```